# Не отображается компонент vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Привет!Я пытался сделать приложение на Vue.js и но компонент header не отображается,хоть ошибок никаких не выдает.

HelloWorld.vue

```
<template>
<header></header>
</template>

<script>
import header from './Header';
export default {
  components:{
    'header': header
  },
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data () {
    return {

    }
  }
}
</script>


<style lang="sass" scoped>

</style>
```

Header.vue

```
<template>
<div class=headerMain>
  <div class=header>
  <div class=header-leftside>
    <img src="/assets/img/group-2.png" alt="brand"><p>bran</p>
    <button class=header-button-browse><span>Browse</span><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></button><input type="text" placeholder="Search for Item...">
    <button class=header-button-search><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
  </div>
  <div class=header-right-side>
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
    <button class=header-account-button><span>My Account</span><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></button>
  </div>

  </div>
</div>

</template>

<script>


export default {
  name: 'header',
  data () {
    return {

    }
  }
}
</script>


<style lang="sass" scoped>

.header
  display: flex
  flex-wrap: wrap
  justify-content: space-around
.header-right-side
  display: flex
  justify-content: flex-end
  align-items: flex-end
.header-leftside
  display: flex
  justify-content: flex-start
  align-items: flex-end
  img
    width: 59px
    height: 51px
    margin-right: 7px
  p
    color: #222222
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif
    font-weight: 300
    font-size: 24px
    text-transform: uppercase
    margin: 0
    &:after
      content: "D"
      color: #f16d7f
      font-size: 24px
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif
      font-weight: 900
  input
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6
    width: 250px
    padding: 9.5px
    margin: 0
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif
    font-weight: 300
    border-left: none
    border-right: none
    &:focus
      outline: none
.header-button-browse
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif
  font-weight: 300
  background-color: #f5f5f5
  outline: none
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6
  font-size: 14px
  padding: 9px
  color: #222222
  margin-left: 19px
  span
    margin-right: 7px
.header-button-search
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif
  font-weight: 300
  background-color: #f5f5f5
  outline: none
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6
  font-size: 14px
  padding: 9px
  color: #222222
  margin: 0px
.header-right-side
  a
    text-decoration: none
    color: #222222
    font-size: 25px
    margin-left: 15px
    &:hover
      text-decoration: none
      color: #222222
.header-account-button
  background-color: #f16d7f
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif
  font-weight: 400
  font-size: 15px
  color: #ffffff
  padding: 9px
  padding-left: 13px
  padding-right: 13px
  outline: none
  border: none
  margin-left: 8px
  span
    margin-right: 7px

</style>
```

Как мне исправить данную проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так назовите компонент по-человечески, а не именем СТАНДАРТНОГО HTML5 тега.
Например **AppHeader**.

Comment: Моя ошибочка,я доже не подумал об этом,спасибо!

Comment: Вот тут посмотрите общепринятый синтаксис: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2